# Incluir vírgula em resultados vindos do banco de dados

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela onde a estrutura é a seguinte:

> IDEstoques | IDProdutos | Tamanhos | Cores | Estoques

Nela armazendo os tamanhos, cores e estoques de cada produto. Porém estou precisando trazer do banco de dados as seguintes informações:

```
Tamanhos: P,M, G    
Cores: Azul, Amarelo, Vermelho
```

Consegui trazer apenas os tamanhos da seguinte forma:

```
$sqlEstoques = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_estoques WHERE IDProdutos = '".$jmBusca->IDProdutos."';");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlEstoques) > 0){
   $resultado = array();
   while($jmEstoques = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEstoques)){
         $resultado[] = $jmEstoques["Tamanho"];
   }
    $visualizar .= "<div class='col-lg-12' style='font-size: 14px; text-align: left'><strong>Tamanhos:</strong>". implode(",",$resultado);
    $visualizar .= "</div>";
}

Saída: Tamanho: P,M,G
```

Como eu faria para trazer também as cores?

```
Cores: Azul, Amarelo, Vermelho
```

Comment: Da mesma forma que você fez com os tamanhos, salvando eles num array e depois com implode. Alguma dificuldade que você encontrou e não colocou na pergunta? Você pode [edit] pra ficar mais claro :)

Comment: Olá gmsantos. Desculpe, não consegui entender muito bem. Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: troca `$jmEstoques["Tamanho"];` para Cores.

Comment: Certo. Já fiz isso, mas não consegui entender como posso salvar em um array e depois jogar para um implode para pegar o tamanho e as cores vindas do BD. Tenho que criar 02 querys e 02 laços?

Comment: itere uma fez, salve duas variáveis.

Comment: Desculpe gmsantos, realmente não consegui entender. Teria como me dar um exemplo baseado no meu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enquanto você itera, salve em outra variável as cores:

```
$sqlEstoques = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM loja_estoques WHERE IDProdutos = '".$jmBusca->IDProdutos."';");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlEstoques) > 0){
   $tamanhos= array();
   $cores= array();
   while($jmEstoques = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEstoques)){
       $tamanhos[] = $jmEstoques["Tamanho"];
       $cores[] = $jmEstoques["Cores"];
   }
   $visualizar .= "<div class='col-lg-12' style='font-size: 14px; text-align: left'><strong>Tamanhos:</strong>". implode(",",$tamanhos)."</div>";
   $visualizar .= "<div class='col-lg-12' style='font-size: 14px; text-align: left'><strong>Cores:</strong>". implode(",",$cores)."</div>";
}
```

Recomendo que estude um pouco a parte de lógica de programação, vejo que faltam alguns conceitos básicos. Leia um pouco também algumas perguntas sobre segurança, principalmente como evitar [SQL Injection em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL%20Injection%20em%20PHP).

Comment: Perfeito gmsantos. Obrigado.